# Change Github account in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have used one Github account to push an android project to Github from Android Studio. Now I have created another account on Github and want to push my another android project to this new account. But I am not able to find any option to change the Github account in Android Studio. It keeps pushing from the previous account and hence results in this error:

> remote: Permission to new_username/repository_name.git denied to old_username.
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/new_username/repository_name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 on Windows OS.

Comment: What are the exact steps that you perform which give the above error? Are you starting a new project or are you pushing the same project to both accounts?

Answer (score 39):

Go to: 
**Setting --> Version Control --> GitHub --> Change you username.**

[image]

Comment: I tried by logging in with the Google Account which I have used in my new Github account and then push but the error remains same. It is pushing using my previous Github account only. Actually I need to change my Github account.

Comment: I tried this too and also tested the account by pressing 'Test' button but even then it is using my previous Github account i.e getting same error.

Comment: nice 1 @NirDuan, the answer Helped me & upvoted, and please edit your answer with this line **Auth Type should be = Password**.

Comment: My 'git config user.name' is showing a different account then what is display in the Version control?

Answer (score 29):

## Step 1

Change file `config` in directory `.git` that located in your project folder

[image: lala]

## Step 2

In terminal @ current project, type:
`git credential-manager uninstall`

Cheers~

Comment: But that does uninstall the credential-manager. What can I do if I still need it?

Comment: i think optimum solution is step 1, after changed android studio git name into preferences,thx a lot.

Answer (score 28):

Uncheck the **Use Credentials Helper** from **Settings** -> **Version Control** -> **Git**. Then log in using the desired account and select the account you want to continue with from **Settings** -> **Version Control** -> **GitHub**.

[image: How to Uncheck use credentials helper]

Comment: this one solved it. Thanks ✌

Comment: What do you mean by "log in using the desired account"? Where to log in? In my case I logged in via third-side Git client, later uncheck-check "Use credential helper" helped.

Answer (score 14):

In my case none of working. This way works for me.

**Steps:**

1. Open **Settings** of Android studio
2. Select **Appearance & Behavior**
3. Select **System Settings**
4. Select **Passwords**
5. Select **Do not remember passwords**
6. Click on **OK**

Now its time to **Push** your source code to Git, Android studio would **ask** for **new username** and its **password**.

Reference screenshot.

[image]

**Done**

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and had solved it.
With current Android Studio 3.5 we can add several github account 

[image]

with several github account added we can select one for the default for specific project.

**or**

change the git username and email:

- git config user.name "your username"
- git config user.email "youremail.com"

add --global if you want change for global config

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not the answer you are wanting, but you can probably solve this by finding out where the project code is stored by android studio and changing the git remote there.

For example, if you want to change where the main repository you push to, enter this in the command line when inside the project directory:
`git remote set-url origin <new-url-from-github>`

Comment: My repository url is correct but Android Studio is using my previous Github account to push the code.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using the command line and as it asked my login credentials, I was able to provide the new account details and hence it worked. But even now I am not able to change my Github account from Android Studio even though I have changed the Settings of Version Control.

Comment: Great! Hopefully that will now work from android studio but if not, you now have an alternative!

Comment: @NitishSrivastava finally got any fix for this github AS madness?? I have faced similar issue in Ubuntu!

Answer (score 4):

I tried all methods, mentioned in all answers, but nothing works, but now I finally found the solution of this problem after stuggling from 1 week, so simply the issue is occuring because in window there is credential manager which is storing your old github credential, so simple steps to solve this issue are :-

step 1) Search Credential Manager
[image]

step 2) click here on Windows credentials
[image]

step 3) Delete your old github credentials
[image]

step 4) You are good to go, simply go to android studio and commit and push your code on github using terminal then it will automatically ask your to login to github then click on login via token using github token, then you are good to go :)

Hope this solutions solves everyone github issue :)

Comment: You are the best! Thank you. This was the only solution that worked here.

Answer (score 1):

When prompted for a username and password, make sure you use an account that has access to the repository.

And in the image of Nir Duan, you must click to the button "test" to verify your connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, all you need to do is open your shell and type--

$git config --global user.name [your username]
$git config --global user.email [your email]

since you probably logged in with git using a different account

Comment: This only changes the metadata which is added to commits. It does not affect the login details for GitHub.

Comment: For me this was the fix I was looking for: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/
For me, github user/password was always correct. However, whenever I commit something, it logged as someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine with re-installing,

`git credential-manager uninstall`
then
`git credential-manager install`
push to repo
`git push --set-upstream origin master`
this will ask for authentication, authenticate and BoooMMMM!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to first go to:
**Setting --> Version Control --> GitHub --> Change you username.** (just like Nir Duan) said.

Then go to:
**VCS --> Checkout of Version Control --> Github**

Log in with new credentials if asked, Change the Git URL and possibly parent directory, Click on clone, open in another window, wait for it to load. close the new window.

Next time you want to push you will see the new repository as part of the options at the top left on the "Push commit" pop-up

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue (working on same PC with diff usernames)

> remote: Permission to new_username/repository_name.git denied to old_username.

Tried all solution mentioned even deleting .gitconfig didn't work.

In the end, solved by following different way :

1. Adding as **Collaborator** to old_username
2. Accept collaboration invitation (Make sure you are logged in to old_username)
3. Push with new_username. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Go VCS>Commit and you will see Author field as shown:

[image]

Change author email Id

Answer (score 0):

## Edit GitHub Accouts

You can **add / remove / replace** GitHub accounts on **Preferences -> Virsion Control -> GitHub**.

[image]

If you have **generated a new access token**, consider removing the deprecated user, and adding the new one using "Log In with token":

[image]