# Changing Github account in Android Studio

Tags: android, github, version-control

I'm trying to push a project from my Android studio but it keeps trying to push using my old account. I have changed the user from my Android studio as well as GitBash.

Here are some screenshots to help you guys understand my problem.

[1](https://gyazo.com/516b6b8aa808d632a5a42e0427813e27) This is how my android studio and gitbash looks like.

[2](https://gyazo.com/599a806faf8e1c6a4beea49ef01257d3)  Android studio is still taking my old account
    Help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Similar question in stack overflow. See here for answers [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929929/change-github-account-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

[image]> Go to:
VCS -> checkout from Version Control -> GitHub -> Change you username and password

Answer (score 1):

**Mac:Prefernces>Version Control>Github**

**Windows:Setting>Version Control>Github**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 4.0.1

Go to VCS->Get from version control

[image]

In new window select Github account and in the right most section you can see older accounts. Now select that account you will able to see 'Add Account' button. You can also logout from your previous accounts as well.

[image]