# Changing gitlab account in android studio

Tags: android, gitlab, move, account

Hello does anyone know how can I change my git lab account in android studio I started a project on my git lab and I want to move it in the new work account I searched but I can't find anything. I reinstalled android studio but when I try to do push or commit it goes to the old account.

Comment: I don't think, there is official support for Gitlab as yet, but it should be similar to Github. Please try solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929929/change-github-account-in-android-studio/38930010)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about the GitLab user account, you can change it by manually editing the `.git/config` file.

Git actions like Pushing and Committing are not done by Android Studio, but by Git. So change the config.

Open the file below in a text editor,

```
<android_project_path>/.git/config
```

then add/change the lines below,

```
[user]
    email = your@email.address
```