# I can't share my project on Github from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I'm getting this issue trying to share my project on github, it says that my credentials are bad but I can't even input my credentials.

I previously shared a project on github with Android studio and it worked fine, but then I deleted the project and the repository on github, and since then I have been facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should [edit/reset your GitHub credentials in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74266808/6309): that way, you can enter your login information again.

Make sure to use as password a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

- either a classic one if you do not want said token to expire
- or a fine-grained one if you want to limit its access to a specific repository, and have an expiration date.