# IntelliJ can't use credentials stored in libsecret to modify remote repo

Tags: git, android-studio, credentials

If I do `git push` on command line everything is fine. Still, Android Studio asks me to login to GitHub if I want to push from there. Seems like it checks for `~/.git_credentials` or something. How do I tell Android Studio to use the stored credentials?

Comment: this is duplicated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929929/change-github-account-in-android-studio) is the question with answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Github account in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929929/change-github-account-in-android-studio)

Comment: Yes thank you, even though it was this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62319859/20806524 telling to disable the property that let me enabling it

Answer (score 0):

**Settings -> Git -> Use credential helper**, actually pretty straight forward, don't know why I didn't look there before.